# Arrays disappear outside of JSON request

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, object

I am attempting to set up an array with the various properties of a YouTube video (you may be thinking this is somewhat superfluous, however I am planning on adding other sources in the future). I am able to add these values into the array within the JSON request, but once I get out of it, they just disappear. Any ideas?

```
var socialPosts = new Array(); 
$.getJSON('https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?author=google&max-results=5&v=2&alt=jsonc&orderby=published', function(data) {
    for(var i=0; i<data.data.items.length; i++) { //for each YouTube video in the request
        socialPosts[i]={date:Date.parse(data.data.items[i].uploaded), title:data.data.items[i].title,source:"YouTube", thumbnail:data.data.items[i].thumbnail.hqDefault, url:'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' + data.data.items[i].id}; //Add values of YouTube video to array
    }
    console.log(socialPosts[0].date); //This returns the correct data
});
console.log(socialPosts[0].date); //This returns with undefined
```

Comment: Learn asynchronous request.

Comment: You are retrieving asynchronous data with `$.getJSON`, and you can only work on the data in a callback function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to access results of Ajax `asyn` call which are *not* yet returned. You need to use result in *call back* function or pass the results to *some function*.

```
var socialPosts = new Array(); 
$.getJSON('https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?author=google&max-results=5&v=2&alt=jsonc&orderby=published', function(data) {
    for(var i=0; i<data.data.items.length; i++) { //for each YouTube video in the request
        socialPosts[i]={date:Date.parse(data.data.items[i].uploaded), title:data.data.items[i].title,source:"YouTube", thumbnail:data.data.items[i].thumbnail.hqDefault, url:'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' + data.data.items[i].id}; //Add values of YouTube video to array
    }
    console.log(socialPosts[0].date); //This returns the correct data
    somefun(socialPosts[0].date); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Because that is an Ajax function and it happens async meaning the code outside the closure executes before the call is finished