# Why can't I access array outside of JSON request?

Tags: jquery, json

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16937783/arrays-disappear-outside-of-json-request) helps me understand the reason why but it's a little brief on the solution.

[The documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/#jqxhr-object) mentions the callback functions `.done()`, `.fail()` and `.always()` but I've tried .done() and couldn't get my variable outside the call.

Here is my relevant code:

```
var countries = [];

$.getJSON("js/flags.json", function(data) {
    $(data.flags).each(function(i) {
        countries.push(data.flags[i]);
    });
    console.log(countries);    // returns a big ol array :)
});
console.log(countries);    // returns an empty array :(
```

I just want to be able to use this array globally. What am I missing?

Comment: The problem is *timing*, not global availability of a variable.  The last line runs long before `countries` is populated.  That's why you need to run all your logic inside of the callback functions.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that the console logs those in reverse (cause the last is executed before the first finishes. So that's the solution? Just run everything inside?

Comment: Unfortunately, yes.  Event-based programming is sensitive to [callback hell](http://callbackhell.com/).  You can avoid it somewhat by linking together dependencies with [promises](https://api.jquery.com/promise/).

Comment: @mellamokb: OP already uses jquery (and for them A+ may be not required yet)

Comment: @zerkms: Good point, updated my comment.

Answer (score 0):

What [u/Adi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1298762/adil) mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16937783/arrays-disappear-outside-of-json-request) is that in an Ajax call, the a meaning asynchronous, when you try to console log the countries array the Ajax call is not done yet and so the array is empty.

What I would do is wrap the Ajax call in a function and pass a callback to that function:

```
function someCallBackFunction(arr){
   console.log(arr)
}

function yourFunction(someCallBackFunction){
  $.getJSON("js/flags.json", function(data) {

    $(data.flags).each(function(i) {
        countries.push(data.flags[i]);
    });
    console.log(countries);

    someCallbackFunction(countries)
  });
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to access the data in my JSON file NOT asyc?

Comment: If you don't want to make an Ajax call check out this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12995560/how-to-locally-fetch-json-without-ajax). Otherwise if you stick with Ajax there is no way, I know of, to make a non async call.

Comment: I found a way here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2765411/is-it-possible-to-set-asyncfalse-to-getjson-call